# In Stargate, what has happened to the children in the pyramid?

Tags: stargate, stargate-1994

In an earlier scene in *Stargate* where Jackson and Colonel O'Neil had been captured by the henchmen of Ra, and after some butt kicking, O'Neil couldn't shoot Ra with the stolen weapon due to the presence of children surrounding his/her throne. How about the end final scene where they teleport the a-bomb up to the pyramid, were children still in the pyramid? If so why not just shoot the kids in the first scene?

Comment: Hey! Collateral damage! They were in the wrong place at the wrong time.

Comment: Congratulations, this question is the winner of the [corresponding topic challenge](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2681/49).

Comment: I personally hate questions that ask why didn't they kill the children earlier - instead of asking why didn't they kill the children later or preferably not at all.  Remember that movie characters - unlike their actors - haven't read the script and don't know what's going to happen later.  They can't say "hay, we're gonna kill the kids later anyway so we might as well mow 'em down right now.  PS Ra - who you call she, is a he.

Comment: @M.A.Golding what an awfully boring comment, nobody cares what you like. I was not talking about actors, and their choices, but the story in general, how can anyone even think such a weird way? The actor playing Ra is a he, but in the role he is extremely androgynous and my question was referring to that point with "his/her".

Answer (score 28, accepted):

**Because they had no choice in the end.**

Recall that the original bomb was merely intended to destroy the stargate so that it could not be used to threaten Earth.

However, the bomb had been altered by Ra to be 100 times more destructive than the original. **Essentially it was a planet wrecker.**

Consequently, unable to stop the countdown or disable the device O'Neil and Jackson used the only option available. Send it back into Ra's ship **in space** to save both Earth and the desert planet (that would eventually be called Abydos)...and perhaps, not coincidentally, blow Ra to hell.

Assuming the children were still on the pyramid, which seems likely, they were also killed.

Comment: Kill the kids, nuke the alien home planet, and be home in time for cornflakes!

Comment: Afair, the children were running away from Ra in an earlier scene, but there was no way to recognize whether they just left the room and were still on the ship or used the opportunity to leave the ship at this time. But neither could O'Neill and Jackson know this. Lacking any evidence, you can decide for yourself, how it ended.

Answer (score 5):

Great question! I was one of the Ra kids (one of the twins) and we actually filmed a whole scene where we were saved. We were supposed to transport back down when the bomb transported up to the ship. When Ra is staring at the transporter and getting angry at the bomb showing up, he was getting angry at us leaving him. After we are saved, we walk out into the light, squinting as if we hadn't been outside in a while (which doesn't make too much sense since there is an earlier scene when some of us are outside with Ra when James Spader turns on Ra). I wondered if they cut the scene because we were missing one of the Ra kids during the filming of us being saved, but we had already filmed the scene walking out into the light. He was one of the older kids who was cut because he didn't get along with Jaye Davidson. I saw another post about this, gotta update that forum too.

Comment: You were seriously one of the kids? How awesome is that! Thanks for the background story.